# What's the difference between RECTL and RECT?

Tags: winapi

According to MSDN, RECT and RECTL are identical structures. Is there any difference between them at all and if not whats the point of having both of them instead of just one?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's no difference between them, as documented in the MSDN article.  To understand why they both exist, you have to go back in history, back to Windows version 3 and earlier.  Those were *16-bit* versions of Windows, unlike the versions of Windows that everybody uses today.  The Windows SDK version for Windows 3.1 declared the RECT structure like this, in windows.h:

```
typedef struct tagRECT
{
    int left;
    int top;
    int right;
    int bottom;
} RECT;
```

And the ole2.h header file declared RECTL using **long** for the structure elements.  16-bit C and C++ compilers back then implemented *int* as a 16-bit type, fitting the word size of a 16-bit processor, and implemented *long* as a 32-bit type.

32-bit compilers, as used in modern Windows versions, made *int* a 32-bit type, fitting the word size of a 32-bit processor.  And kept *long* as a 32-bit type.  Which made the difference between the two structure types disappear.

Comment: Is there any reason the current `RECT` definition uses `LONG` rather than `INT`?